# making node sass generate a class but also a mixin?

Tags: css, sass

I am fairly new to sass and I was thinking if using some variables I could generate some utility classes and also mixins that I can either use in the html or just within another sass file without importing all styles.

So there are two questions:

1. I see that if I import '_color.scss' all classes are automatically added to the imported file. any ways I can just output the ones I want? I know you can do that with some node extension but this is not what I am looking for, wanted something that can be used with the sass extension.
2. This is what a I want to achieve:

_colors files:

```
$primary: black;
$secondary: blue;

//generate the classes and the mixins with the name of the variables like:
.bg-primary {
  background-color: $primary;
}

@mixin bg-primary {
  background-color: $primary;
}
```

so with the above I could either use the color by importing the classes to the root or I can just use the mixin in a component without needing to import all classes. There might be a easier way to do this, so any alternative is welcome.

UPDATE:

Here is the utility mixin:

```
@mixin u($prop, $value: null) {
  @if ($prop and $value) {
      #{$prop}: call($prop, $value);
  } @else {
    .u-#{$prop} {
      @each $item, $value in $color {
        &-#{$item} {
          #{$prop}: $value;
        };
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

here is the color files changed:

```
    $color: (
  primary-main: rgb(25, 118, 210),
  secondary-main: rgb(220, 0, 78),
  error-main: rgb(244, 67, 54),
  warning-main: rgb(255, 152, 0),
  info-main: rgb(33, 150, 243),
  success-main: rgb(76, 175, 80),
  text-primary: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87),
  text-secondary: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54),
  text-disabled: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38),
);

@function color($value:null) {
  @if($value) {
    @if map-has-key($color, $value) {
      @return map-get($map: $color, $key: $value);
    }
  }
    @return $color
};
```

The issue now is that for each property I want I need to create a function with the same name. Is there any way I can make this part dynamic? so I don't need to create a function for fonts, bg etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it,

so I aggregate all tokens in a map of maps.

and then I can do this:

```
@mixin u($prop, $value: null) {
  @if ($prop and $value) {
      #{$prop}: get-tokens($tokens, $prop, $value);
  } @else {
    .u-#{$prop} {
      @each $item, $value in map-get($tokens, $prop) {
        &-#{$item} {
          #{$prop}: $value;
        };
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

tokens:

```
$tokens:(
  border-color: $color,
  color: $color,
  background-color: $color,
  font-size: $font-size,
  font-weight: $font-weight,
  font-family: $font-family,
);

@function get-tokens ($map, $keys...) {
  @if type-of($map) != 'map' {
    @error 'The argument $map: `#{$map}` is of incorrect type: `#{type-of($map)}`. Type of `Map` is required!';
  }

  @each $key in $keys {
    $map: map-get($map, $key);
  }

  @return $map;
}
```